# recursion program to add and subtract a number

Tags: java, recursion

I want to implement this program but it throws errors on every function call and runs an infinite loop.

```
class abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=16;
        calll(n);
    }
    static int calll(int n)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
            n=n-5;
            calll(n);
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            n=n+5;
            calll(n);
            return n;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is this homework?, You are missing base condition in recursion.

Comment: What's the program's purpose? You are adding and subtracting from `n` so it will never finish.

Comment: You call all the times your method calll(n) before the return, so it goes never to the the return. Try on paper your example, you'll understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no end condition to your function.

Whether n is greater than 5 or not you run the calll function, which then runs the calll function again to infinite.

You need a conditon that will end the recursion, for instance changing the call function to this:

```
static int calll(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        n=n-5;
        calll(n);
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return n;
    }

}
```

However the function is still rather pointless as you don't actually do anything with n. Keep in mind that the n that you define in the main function is never modified.